# Is there anyway to use LIKE in NoSQL Command on non primary Key?

Tags: cassandra, nosql, cql, cassandra-3.0

I am selecting from Cassandra database using the LIKE operator on non primary key.

```
select * from "TABLE_NAME" where "Column_name" LIKE '%SpO%' ALLOW FILTERING;

Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="LIKE restriction is only
supported on properly indexed columns. parameter LIKE '%SpO%' is not valid."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, "yes" there is a way to query with `LIKE` on a non-Primary Key component.  You can do this with a SASI (Storage Attached Secondary Index) Index.  Here is a quick example:

```
CREATE TABLE testLike (key TEXT PRIMARY KEY, value TEXT) ;

CREATE CUSTOM INDEX  valueIdx ON testLike (value)
  USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex'
  WITH OPTIONS={'mode':'CONTAINS'};
```

As your query requires to match a string *within* a column, and not just a prefix or suffix you'll want to pass the `CONTAINS` option on index creation.

After writing some data, your query works for me:

```
> SELECT * FROM testlike WHERE value LIKE '%SpO%';

 key | value
-----+--------------
   C | CSpOblahblah
   D | DSpOblahblah

(2 rows)
```

**WARNING!!!**

This query is extremely inefficient, and will probably time out in a large cluster, unless you also filter by a partition key in your `WHERE` clause.  It's important to understand that while this functionality works *similar* to how a relational database would, that Cassandra is definitely *not* a relational database. It is simply not designed to handle queries which incur a large amount of network time polling multiple nodes for data.